# Remove API Gateway resource in AWS prod stage

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-api-gateway

I had a AWS API Gateway which had 3 resources(Saml,Reports,Program). In the stages we had (Prod, Stage). I can able to see that prod stage has extra resource (Saml, Reports,Program, **persons** ). It is present only in prod stage resources. I want to remove that resource but there is no delete option in Prod stage to remove the resource "persons". This is causing issue. Can anyone please help and let me know how to remove the resource from Stage Prod specifically. All I can find is to remove the complete stage but not specific resource.

[image: Prod stage resources]

Regards,
Raghu

Answer (score 1):

Just need to deploy API then both prod AND stage will have same api's.